# Oracle - Birthday Date Math

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

Hi all I have no code here to show because I can't wrap my head around a clean way to do this.  In our table I have a birthday column that is a timestamp.  I need to find everyone whose birthday occurs within the next 3 months.

So I know I can add 3 months to the sysdate, but how I do the date comparison while ignoring the year has me thrown for a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge is to get the number of months between now and the next birthday interval. The `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` function combined with dividing by 12 gets us close, but we have to deal with the decimal dust and convert the remainder to something useful. I can think of two ways to deal with that: `MOD()` and `CEIL()`.

Using `CEIL` we would take the difference between the age-to-be on the next birthday and the present age and use that in the predicate. In this case the result is in decimal years, so we need to compare to a quarter year (3/12):

```
where (ceil(months_between(sysdate, b.birthday)/12) - 
      months_between(sysdate, b.birthday)/12) <= 3/12;
```

That's a bit clunky. Alternatively, `MOD` would give us the remainder of months to go, so subtracting `MOD` from 12 gives us the months left to go:

```
where (12 - mod(months_between(sysdate, b.birthday),12)) <= 3;
```

Here it is in action with sample data:

```
with b as 
  (select date '1990-05-10' birthday from dual union all
  select date '1970-09-23' from dual union all
  select date '2000-04-02' from dual union all
  select date '1948-11-12' from dual)
select 
  b.birthday,
  months_between(sysdate, b.birthday) months,
  months_between(sysdate, b.birthday)/12 years,
  ceil(months_between(sysdate, b.birthday)/12) age_to_be,
  ceil(months_between(sysdate, b.birthday)/12) - months_between(sysdate, b.birthday)/12 period_to_birthday,
  mod(months_between(sysdate, b.birthday),12) mod_months,
  12 - mod(months_between(sysdate, b.birthday),12) months_diff
from b
where (12 - mod(months_between(sysdate, b.birthday),12)) <= 3;
-- Or
--where (ceil(months_between(sysdate, b.birthday)/12) - 
--      months_between(sysdate, b.birthday)/12) <= 3/12;
```

---

**EDIT:** I'll leave my old and incorrect answer here for reference and I'll just look the other way.

Just use `ADD_MONTHS()` and `LAST_DAY()` to find all rows where the birthday is inside of a calculated value. No need to worry about the year component, you are not working with string literals.

This example casts `sysdate` as a `timestamp`, then gets the last day of the current month and adds three months to that:

```
select add_months(last_day(cast(sysdate as timestamp)),3) from dual;
```

So using that logic, you can:

```
select *
from your_table
where birthday <= add_months(last_day(cast(sysdate as timestamp)),3);
```

Or just:

```
select *
from your_table
where birthday <= add_months(last_day(sysdate),3);
```

Oracle nicely handles the data type conversion for you.

Comment: This makes the assumption the OP is talking about the date of birth - whereas I'm pretty sure they mean birthday, i.e. the anniversary of someone's birth. This logic would say that my birthday has already gone - but in September I'm pretty sure my wife will be baking my birthday cake :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Zoink! You are correct. It took me a few moments before the face-palm realization. I updated the answer with an alternative solution. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is a bit complicated, because of end-of-the-year wrapping.  But this should work:

```
where (extract(month from sysdate) < 10 and
       to_char(birthday, 'MM-DD') between to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD') and
                                          to_char(add_month(sysdate, 3), 'MM-DD')
       ) or
       (extract(month from sysdate) >= 10 and
        (to_char(birthday, 'MM-DD') >= to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD')  or
         to_char(birthday, 'MM-DD') <= to_char(add_month(sysdate, 3), 'MM-DD')
        )
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

A person's birthday (anniversary) in the current year, given their date of birth is:

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y') + (dob - TRUNC(dob,'Y'))
```

You can tell if this is within the next three months with something like:

```
SELECT 'Yes' FROM dual
WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y') + (dob - TRUNC(dob,'Y'))
BETWEEN SYSDATE AND ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,3);
```

There is only one small problem, that is if the person was born on 31 December in a Leap year, this method has an out-by-one error when you run it in a non-leap year (i.e. it will not identify that person as begin within the next three months until the 1st of October).